# Capture textual snapshot of pseudo terminal

Tags: terminal, console, tty

My question is related to [Keyboard and Console](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-20.html), but I want to do it for an arbitrary pseudo terminal, and not just the built-in Linux ones.

Also, I'm not interested in [a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353253), I just want the current state.

I'd imagine that if I `cat` the resulting file with the cursor at 0x0 and same terminal settings, the screen would look exactly like it did when the snapshot was taken.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK normal shell, nor default Linux console don't provide such facilities, but many terminal emulation programs do - e.g. KDE's Konsole has the option "Save output as..."

If your current terminal emulator doesn't support that (e.g. you're on the system console, text mode, or on a genuine serial terminal, not emulated), you can always launch the GNU Screen command: `screen`. It provides hundreds of rich functionalities to the console, and among them there's *hardcopy* - `ctrl-A h` saves currently visible screen contents to a file *hardcopy.[nr]*. More on the subject in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Hardcopy).

Comment: I'd like to do it programmatically...

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: `screen -X` allows you to send arbitrary command to an already running screen session, so you can execute the command to dump a hardcopy from a script running outside Screen.

Comment: It also doesn't handle Unicode or colors :(

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: I'm fairly sure it does, but you'll need to give the config files some TLC.